# Using a server to read my Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

I have being trying to seek an answer to this problem for a number of weeks and have been down a number of blind alleys, and have not been able to get a definitive answer.

All I want to do is access my facebook page from a server application (C#, using the C# SDK)

My issue is to do with access tokens.  The server has no user interface, so cannot reauthenticate a user every 60 days to renew the access token. I was advised that if I used an App access token I would be OK because this does not need to go through a  renewal process.

but when I try this type of construct

```
        string accesstoken = m_AppId & "|" & m_AppSecret;
        Facebook.FacebookClient fb  = New Facebook.FacebookClient(accesstoken);
        Facebook.JsonObject x  = fb.Get("me")
```

I get an authentication error because I cannot access "me" from a App Access token.

I have read the docs and they seem to imply that all access tokens will expire eventually, but what I cannot reconcile, is that mobile facebook apps only ever authenticate a human user once, when first installed and then never reauthenticate. These mobile Apps are doing pretty similar data access to what I need.

How are they doing it without needing to renew access tokens?

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions. The User Access Token is prolongued by the usage of the respective FB App. That's written in the docs as well

Comment: It is not meant to be a duplicate - I did comment on that one you referenced that I was going to rephrase the original in a more meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access a Facebook Page, the extended access_token does not expire. Make sure you covert the access_token to a long-lived one using the API. You only need to authenticate the user once to get the page access_token. [See this tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/2013/09/17/facebook-api-getting-a-long-lived-access-token/).

Comment: Thank you for this. The trouble is that this token does expire after 60 days.  This means that my server would stop working after 60 days. There is no direct user interaction. It is a server.   So how do mobile apps do this. Does anyone know ?